# Calculating $\pi$ by inscribing and outscribing $2^n$-gons

Tags: circles, pi, polygons

I am trying to approximate $\pi$ by using inscribed and outscribed(?) polygons. I already have a formula for the circumference of the inscribed ngons:

square= √(2×4,

octagon= √(2-√(2))×8,

16gon= √(2-√(2+√(2)))×16,

32gon= √(2-√(2+√(2+√(2))))×32...

the circumference rapidly approaches tau$(2\pi)$

but im having trouble finding a formula for the outscribed 16gon. Of course I can just use a geometry program, but that doesn't help me find a generalized formula. I came up with:

sauare= 2×4

octagon= (2√(2)-2)×8

but no further. I couldn't find any formula for the outher ngons on the internet.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula.

Comment: I think the word is "circumscribed" :-)

Comment: Is the point here that you want to express these formulas in terms of radicals? Because if you're just looking for some formula, these are well-known; see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) in the right-hand sidebar ("circumscribed circle diameter" and "inscribed circle diameter").

Comment: I seem to have given a formula for this in an answer to [Approximating the area of the disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2526704) (November 2017), but (to my annoyance) the question has been closed, deleted, and hidden. I'll try to refresh my memory, check the work, and post something here, if it's any good (when I can find time, perhaps later today).

Comment: @CalumGilhooley thar would be very kind, yes

Comment: I'm sorry about the long delay. If it continues, I'll give you my detailed excuses! (I'll delete these comments when I've posted an answer.)